# Check duplicates in html table based on first two column values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement where i need to check for duplicate data in html table. I have two columns product name and batch. As per the requirement product name can be repeated,but if same batch repeats for same product name,i need to show an alert with corresponding batch and product name in the alert. I heve created a snippet below which represents the issue more appropriately.

Below table contains two rows with same product name and batch for which i want to show an alert.

Please help me!

```js
function highlightDuplicates() {
 
 
      a1 =0;
      a2 =0;
      
      $('#myTable .tbody tr').find('input').each(function() {
       // check if there is another one with the same value
         if ($('#myTable td:nth-child(1)').find('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').size() > 1 && $('#myTable td:nth-child(2)').find('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').size() > 1) {
             
         alert("Duplicate found")
                   return false; 
              
          } 
      });
      }
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    
    }
th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: black;
   
}
th,td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Batch</th>
    <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="a"></td><td><input type="text" value="b"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="c"></td><td><input type="text" value="d"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="a"></td><td><input type="text" value="b"></td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
   </table> 

   <br>
   <button onclick="return highlightDuplicates()">Check Duplicates</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
function highlightDuplicates() {
 
  $('#myTable .tbody tr').each(function(index1){
      var row = $(this)
      var row_val1 = row.find("td:nth-child(1) input").val()
      var row_val2 = row.find("td:nth-child(2) input").val()
      $('#myTable .tbody tr').each(function(index2){
          
         var compare_row = $(this)
         var compare_row_val1 = compare_row.find("td:nth-child(1) input").val()
      var compare_row_val2 = compare_row.find("td:nth-child(2) input").val()
         
         if(index1!=index2 && row_val1==compare_row_val1 && row_val2==compare_row_val2){
            
            row.addClass('duplicate')
            compare_row.addClass('duplicate')
         }
      })
   })
   
   if($('tr.duplicate').length>0){
      alert('Duplicates found')
   }
 }
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    
    }
th {
    background-color: #009999;
    color: black;
   
}
th,td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
tr.duplicate td{
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Batch</th>
    <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="a"></td><td><input type="text" value="b"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="c"></td><td><input type="text" value="d"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="a"></td><td><input type="text" value="b"></td>
    </tr> 
    </tbody>
   </table> 

   <br>
   <button onclick="return highlightDuplicates()">Check Duplicates</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

You can track the values this way and check them

```
function highlightDuplicates() {
  var currentValues = [];

  $('#myTable .tbody tr').find('input').each(function() {
   // check if there is another one with the same value
     if (currentValues.includes($(this).val())) {
         alert("Duplicate found");
         return false;
     }

     currentValues.push($(this).val());
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/bgd7mL3r/

```
$('#highlightDuplicatesBtn').on('click', function() {

  var uniqueItems = [];
  var duplicates = [];

  $('.productInput').each(function() {
    var batchInput = $('.batchInput', $(this).parent().parent());
    var item = 'Product: ' + $(this).val() + ', Batch: ' + batchInput.val();

    if (uniqueItems.indexOf(item) != -1) {
      duplicates.push(item);
      alert('Duplicates' + item);
    }
    uniqueItems.push(item);
  });

  console.log(duplicates);
}), false;
```

With some slight changes in  the markup:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Batch</th>
      <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="a" class="productInput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="b" class="batchInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="c" class="productInput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="d" class="batchInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="a" class="productInput">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="b" class="batchInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<button id="highlightDuplicatesBtn">Check Duplicates</button>
```